# Error in parsing <attribute value> pairs using pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a log file using pyparsing.
The structure of the log file entries is like this:

```
information line 1
information line 2
...
information line n
attribute name 1 = attribute value 1
attribute name 2 = attribute value 2
...
attribute name n = attribute value n
```

I have written this grammar to parse this block of text:

```
NL = Suppress(LineEnd())
infoline = OneOrMore(Word(alphas + ".-")) + NL
attrib_value_pair = OneOrMore(Word(alphas)) + Suppress("=") + \
                    OneOrMore(Word(alphanums + ".")) + NL
data = OneOrMore(infoline) + OneOrMore(attrib_value_pair)

parsed_data = data.parseString(trace_block)
```

I am getting this error while parsing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "filter.py", line 100, in <module>
get_trace_block()
File "filter.py", line 25, in get_trace_block
filter_trace(trace_block)
File "filter.py", line 53, in filter_trace
get_attrib_name_value_pairs(trace_block[2:len(trace_block)])
File "filter.py", line 94, in get_attrib_name_value_pairs
parsed = data.parseString(trace_block)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1006, in parseString
raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of line (at char 70), (line:2, col:26)
```

Sample lines from the log file:

```
A valid message has been received from a peer
Message type  is A
local ip = 10.7.1.10
local port = 3000
remote ip = 10.7.1.20
remote port = 3001
```

Any idea where it is going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really quite close. Pyparsing's whitespace skipping by default includes newlines, so your infoline `OneOrMore` will read past the single line of info, and actually will read even into the "local ip" of the first attribute. Since your parser is line-oriented and you are explicitly showing where newlines can occur in your parser, then you should tell pyparsing *not* to skip newlines as ignorable whitespace. Do this before defining any of your grammar elements:

```
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' \t')
```

Now you will start to see better results from your parser.

Some other tips:

- use Group around infoline and attrib_value_pair to add structure to your parsed data.
- When you parse your infolines, the OneOrMore type expression will give you a line like `['A', 'valid', 'message', 'has', 'been', 'received', 'from', 'a', 'peer']` Wrap infoline with `originalTextFor`, and this will restore the matched text for the infoline to just "A valid message etc...." as a single string

Good luck with your pyparsing work!

Comment: Paul, your solution works fine. Thanks. Just one question about the suggestion about Group. Shouldn't it be Combine instead of Group. I think Group will not display the tokens as a whole string, whereas Combine would do the trick.